# Streaming from mongodb in AWS lambda times out

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which connects to a mongodb database and streams some records from the database.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    let url = event.mongodbUrl;
    let collectionName = event.collectionName;

    MongoClient.connect(url, (error, db) => {
       if (error) {
           console.log("Error connecting to mongodb: ${error}");
           callback(error);
       } else {
           console.log("Connected to mongodb");
           let events = [];
           console.log("Streaming data from mongodb...");
           let mongoStream = db.collection(collectionName).find().sort({ _id : -1 }).limit(500).stream();

           mongoStream.on("data", data => {
               events.push(data);
           });

           mongoStream.once("end", () => {
               console.log("Stream ended");
               db.close(() => {
                   console.log("Database connection closed");
                   callback(null, "Lambda function succeeded!!");
               });
           });
       }
    });
};
```

When the stream is ended I close the database connection and call the callback function which should end the lambda function. This works locally using [node-lambda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-lambda), but when I try to run it in AWS lambda I get all of the logs, including `console.log("Database connection closed");` coming through, but the callback doesn't seem to be called, so the function always times out, despite the last log occurring a few seconds before the time out.

I can force it to end using `context.succeed()`, but that seems to be deprecated when using node version 4, so I want to avoid using it. How can I stop this function from timing out in AWS lambda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line at the beginning of your handler function:

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
```

Comment: Yep, this fixes the problem, thanks. Do you know why the event loop is not empty at the callback in the code in question?

Comment: @Carasel no idea, nor do I have any idea why AWS would think that continuing to run a Lambda process after you've told it you're done by invoking the callback was a good default behavior. You might have some luck by using [why-is-node-running](https://github.com/mafintosh/why-is-node-running) to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
 mongoStream.once("end", callback);
```

This is also calling back with err and result but will not lose the context.